# How to connect to multiple APIs with the same custom request header name

Tags: php, curl

```
$headers = array(
 'Custom-Key-Name:'. $apikey1,
 'Custom-Key-Name:'. $apikey2,   
 'Content-Type: application/json'
);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Something like that is what im trying to do. I can connect to 1 just fine, but there are 3 separate APIs I need to read from each with their own key, but they want you to use the same key name. When I try it like the way i've written it just reads one of them.

Comment: Show how you're trying to do it to all 3.

Comment: how about reading one after the other, with 3 separate curl calls?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I had tried that before I posted this, but thanks to the answer below, I learned I needed to put a response after each curl call.

Comment: @shonna that is what I meant. glad to see you got an answer that worked for oyu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$headersForA = array(
 'Custom-Key-Name:'. $apikey1,
 'Content-Type: application/json'
);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headersForA);
$responseA = curl_exec($ch);

$headersForB = array(
 'Custom-Key-Name:'. $apikey2,
 'Content-Type: application/json'
);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headersForB);
$responseB = curl_exec($ch);

$headersForC = array(
 'Custom-Key-Name:'. $apikey3,
 'Content-Type: application/json'
);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headersForC);
$responseC = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the same `$ch` to connect to multiple APIs.

Comment: @Barmar there's no inherent reason why you can't.

Comment: I assumed that once you connected to a server you couldn't reuse that handle to connect to a different server.

Comment: You can reset it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php. For the purposes of this question, it really makes no difference.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread who posted it...I dont post on this site much haha. @ryantxr is who I should have thanked! whoops